# AngularJS - access "element" inside scope.$watch callback function

Tags: angularjs, element

For the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qcuennL5/, I want to access "element" inside scope.$watch('$select.isOpened', ...). How can I do it?

```
scope.$watch('$select.isOpened', function(isOpened) {

if(isOpened) {
    //Don't have access to 'element'. Hacked with $('...')
        $('div.dropdown').show();
    } else {
        $('div.dropdown').hide();
}
```

Comment: You have it there as `element` parameter. Just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the access to `element` parameter.

From the chrome debugger, we won't be able to check the closure properties if the property being checked is not used inside the function being executed.

Console statements will print the value properly.

Not sure if this is a chrome bug.

Comment: Vinay K, you don't have access to element inside scope.$watch('$select.isOpened', ...). Just put a breakpoint inside to see.

Comment: with debugger it may not show, try console.log(element)

Comment: @cosmi.nu, please check the console logs in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qcuennL5/1/

Comment: Vinay K, this is correct. When I use console.log(element), I have access to it. Why is this happening? Also please modify your original answer, so that I can vote your answer as useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use jQuery or watch any objects on the scope.

Just use the `ng-show` directive like this ...

```
ng-show="$select.isOpened"
```

**JS/TEMPLATE**

```
template: '<div class="select" ng-click="$select.click(\'I was clicked!\', $event)">' +
                '<div class="select-label">{{title}}</div>' +
                '<div class="select-caret"><span class="select-dropdown"></span></div>' +
                '<div class="dropdown" ng-show="$select.isOpened">This is a dropdown!</div>' +
          '</div>'
```

Also remove the `display` property from `div.dropdown`in your CSS

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/zLh13v1c/)**

**Using $watch**

```
scope.$watch('$select.isOpened', function (isOpened) {
    scope.isOpened =   isOpened;  // assign isOpened to new variable on the scope.

    // Stick the rest of your logic here            
});
```

**HTML**

```
'<div class="dropdown" ng-show="isOpened">This is a dropdown!</div>'
```

Comment: Using `ng-show` is the "angular way" but if you don't mind including jQuery then that's ok. You can still have the `$watch` logic in there and also use the `ng-show` directive.

Comment: dcodesmith, using `ng-show` or not using it is not the real problem inside the code. The real problem is that if you debug my original fiddle and put a breakpoint inside `scope.$watch(...)`, you'll see that `element` is undefined. Also, as Vinay K suggested, if you simply use it (`console.log(element)`) and not trying to evaluate it in the console, you'll have access to `element`. Hope that now you understand what was the real problem in the code.